# Cloud Function writing to Firebase Realtime Database times out

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I can see a new entry is added as soon as I get the URL, but the request hangs and times out. Why?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.add = functions.https.onRequest((request, response)=>
{
    var ref = admin.database().ref("jobs");
    var childRef = ref.push();
    childRef.set
    (
        {
            title: "test",
            pay: 100
        }
    );
})
```

The code is based on the following example. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data

Result

```
{"error":{"code":500,"status":"INTERNAL","message":"function execution attempt timed out"}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloud Functions triggered by HTTP requests need to be terminated by ending them with a `send()`, `redirect()`, or `end()`, otherwise they will continue running and reach the timeout.

From the [terminate HTTP functions section of the documentation on HTTP triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#terminate_http_functions):

> Always end an HTTP function with `send()`, `redirect()`, or `end()`. Otherwise, your function might to continue to run and be forcibly terminated by the system. See also [Sync, Async and Promises](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).

Therefore, in your example, you can end the request by sending a response:

```
exports.add = functions.https.onRequest((request, response)=>
{
    var ref = admin.database().ref("jobs");
    var childRef = ref.push();
    childRef.set
    (
        {
            title: "test",
            pay: 100
        }
    );
    response.status(200).send("OK!");
})
```